# Hanging indents with a Pandoc bibliography

Tags: pdf, pandoc, markdown

I'm using Pandoc / Markdown / LaTeX to write lab reports.

I've opted to not deal with multiple intermediate files for my bibliography. So I have to use this to generate my documents:

```
pandoc --csl=apa.csl lab02.md --bibliography=bibtex.bib -o lab02.pdf
```

This works alright. The issue is that hanging indent does not work. It's easy to solve this through this code block:

```
\begingroup
# References
\setlength{\parindent}{-0.2in}
\setlength{\leftskip}{0.2in}
\setlength{\parskip}{8pt}

<div id="refs"></div>
\endgroup
```

Which is how I am citing references. I have to do this because I have a required section *after* references, otherwise I could simply do `# References` and have it automatically put everything in, and just do that setlength stuff once right at the end of the doc.

My question is concerning how to create a custom command to do this faster, because I like hanging indent in some other sections too. I want do do this both for ease of use and to learn how to make commands. I am having trouble doing this on my own.

Ideally it'd be something like: `\starthang` which maps to

```
\begingroup
# References
\setlength{\parindent}{-0.2in}
\setlength{\leftskip}{0.2in}
\setlength{\parskip}{8pt}
```

And

`\endhang`  which just is an alias for `\endgroup`

The best I have come up with is this, which doesn't seem to work:

```
\newenvironment{hang}
{   {\begingroup
    \setlength{\parindent}{-0.2in}
    \setlength{\leftskip}{0.2in}
    \setlength{\parskip}{8pt}
    }
    {
      \endgroup  
    }
}
```

Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

One [easy solution](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-citeproc/issues/278#issuecomment-429508173) is to use the `hangparas` environment from the hanging package:

[image: Pandoc Bibliography example with hangparas]

````
---
header-includes: |
  \usepackage{hanging}
references:
- id: 'abou-el-haj:1983bury'
  type: article-journal
  title: >-
    Bury St Edmunds Abbey Between 1070 and 1124: A History of Property,
    Privilege, and Monastic Art Production
  container-title: Art History
  page: 1-29
  volume: '6'
  issue: '1'
  DOI: 10/gftmwk
  author:
    - family: Abou-El-Haj
      given: Barbara
  issued:
    - year: 1983
      month: 3
- id: 'abou-el-haj:1991audiences'
  type: article-journal
  title: The audiences for the medieval cult of saints
  container-title: Gesta
  page: 3-15
  volume: '30'
  issue: '1'
  DOI: 10/bhjtnp
  author:
    - family: Abou-El-Haj
      given: Barbara
  issued:
    - year: 1991
---

[@abou-el-haj:1983bury; @abou-el-haj:1991audiences]

# References

```{=latex}
\begin{hangparas}{1em}{1}
```

<div id="refs"></div>

```{=latex}
\end{hangparas}
```
````